# Why am I receiving Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm trying to deploy my application to production, but I receive "**Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API Schema. - configuration has an unknown property 'resolvedModules'. These properties are valid:**" I recently upgraded to the latest stable build of webpacker for Rails 6. I believe its webpacker 4. This error is stemming from my environment.js file - It was working with some minor issues regarding JQuery - which was failing to work globally in certain cases. I thought that, maybe it was a bug in the gem spec that I was using. After commenting out the whole entire environment.js file, it deployed without issue. There is no 'resolvedModules' configuration object in my environment file. Unless its coming from the "@rails/webpacker" require statement. **How can I fix my environment.js file to ProvidePlugin for JQuery and my other dependencies, while fixing the resolvedModules error that I receive during deploy?**

environment.js

```
const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');
const webpack = require('webpack')'

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      moment: 'moment'
  }));

environment.config.set('resolve.alias', {jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'});
module.exports = environment;
```

**UPDATE**

I receive the error below when I deploy with the new changes?

```
DEBUG [4763131a]   Compilation failed:
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'resolvedModules'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           resolvedModules: …
         }
       })
     ]
 - configuration.plugins[0] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
 - configuration.plugins[1] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
 - configuration.plugins[2] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
 - configuration.plugins[3] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
 - configuration.plugins[4] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
 - configuration.plugins[5] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
 - configuration.plugins[6] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
 - configuration.plugins[7] misses the property 'apply'.
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
```

webpack overall config

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sample_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@client-side-validations/client-side-validations": "^0.1.1",
    "@client-side-validations/simple-form": "^0.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.0.0",
    "@yaireo/tagify": "yaireo/tagify",
    "active_storage_drag_and_drop": "^0.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartkick": "^3.2.0",
    "cocoon": "github:nathanvda/cocoon#c24ba53",
    "flow-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "latest",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

**webpacker.yml**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: ['app/assets']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .erb
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

**production.js**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

const environment = require('./environment');

module.exports = environment;
```

Answer (score 4):

Check compatible versions of webpacker in `package.json`. Mine is..

```
"dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `environment.config.set('resolve.alias', {jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'});` with:

```js
environment.config.merge({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't receive an error when using the development environment. But, when I re-deploy, I get the error that I posted in my update.

Comment: When I search for resolvedModule in my project. I only find results in @rails/webpacker.

Comment: it's definitely the environment.js file thats causing the issue. I deploy without a problem, otherwise. I just can't use jquery in production.

Comment: Then we could use more info, like package.json, config/webpacker.yml and production.js, to reproduce.

Comment: I added the config files that you requested to my question body.

Comment: I had to add back toWebpackConfig(); in environment.js

Answer (score -1):

Oddly, toWebpackConfig(); was required for me

After changing `module.exports = environment`, the JS worked within its normal capacity.

the final result for the sake of clarity

```
module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig();
```

I also had a few broken dependencies that weren't initialized but required JQuery. They failed in view, and I was able to eliminate them, entirely.